# Best OCR for extracting text from a plot?

Tags: text, plot, ocr

[image]
<sub>(source: [goldprice.org](http://goldprice.org/NewCharts/gold/images/gold_1d_o_GBP.png))</sub>

Does anyone know of a good ocr that is able to convert this image into text?
I tried [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) but it didn't work out the way I expected.

Comment: What kind of output would you expect from this? "Gold Price GBP634.92△3.07 637, 636, 634, ..."  Or are you trying to extract the graph values?

Comment: the Text Gold Price GBP634.92△3.07 637, 636, 634,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try at first to find the text "Gold Price" or "GBP" (if this text is always the same)
And then you will know the place where that text is places, then just cut that part of image containing the text and proceed OCR to that line separately. 
You can also try Cuneiform:
[link text](https://launchpad.net/cuneiform-linux/+download)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need [Engauge Digitizer](http://digitizer.sourceforge.net/) (Open Source) - Digitizing software that converts an image file showing a graph or map, into numbers.